# Jupyter Notebook not loading notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Notebook that I have been working on for a while now to do some data cleanup for a project. I tried to open it again today and am getting a blank loading screen. I have restarted the server multiple times and have restarted my computer but have had no luck in getting it to load. Each time I try to open the notebook, my computer goes into overdrive, gets hot, fans start up, etc. I am working with a 2GB file in Pandas, so sometimes when running a data heavy command this happens, so I take it as normal.

Here is the screen and the output in my terminal. I haven't had this problem before and am wondering what my options are for saving my work. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7oi2.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem . I solved it by deleting cookies and cache .
If the problem persists pls check this link 
https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3857